# Android service not working when app is closed

Tags: java, android, service, background, android-service

I'm having trouble with an android service that I'm doing. The service is about to get the location of the user every 5 minutes. All seems to go well except when i kill the app, the service won't do nothing. In the code you will ses its checking every 60 seconds I think, but this will change to 5 minutes.

Minimum Target Version: API 23

Target Version: API 29

**Android Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.venomapps.meets">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

<application
    android:name=".Utils.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.RegisterActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Activities.LoginActivity">
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".Services.LocationService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"/>
</application>
```

**Code that executes the service:**

```
AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationService.class);                            intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_START_LOCATION_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), Constants.LOCATION_SERVICE_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60000, pendingIntent);
```

**Service:**

```
public class LocationService extends Service {
private LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
        if (locationResult != null && locationResult.getLastLocation() != null) {
            double latitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLatitude();
            double longitude = locationResult.getLastLocation().getLongitude();
            Log.d("LOCATION_UPDATE", latitude + ", " + longitude);
            stopLocationService();
        }
    }
};

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

public void startLocationService() {
    String channelId = "location_notification_channel";
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            getApplicationContext(),
            channelId
    );
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_app);
    builder.setContentTitle("Location Service");
    builder.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
    builder.setContentText("Running");
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(false);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        if (notificationManager != null && notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId) == null) {
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                    channelId, "Location Service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            );
            notificationChannel.setDescription("This channel is used by location service");
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
    }

    LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    locationRequest.setInterval(8000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            .requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper());
    startForeground(Constants.LOCATION_SERVICE_ID, builder.build());
}

private void stopLocationService(){
    LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
            .removeLocationUpdates(locationCallback);
    stopForeground(true);
    stopSelf();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if(intent != null){
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action != null){
            if(action.equals(Constants.ACTION_START_LOCATION_SERVICE)){
                startLocationService();
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "kill the app"?

Comment: Not to leave it in the background. Swipe it and close it definitely.

Comment: Add some debug logging. When you kill the app, is the `Service` killed? Does the `Service` get restarted?

Comment: I don't understand your code. You trigger the `Service` (ie: call `onStartCommand()` every time the alarm triggers. This then calls `startLocationService()` which sets up the location monitoring again every time. This shouldn't be necessary. You only need to do this once. Please find a howto or tutorial for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AlarmManager is deprecated if used for that purpose. Have a look at [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager).

Comment: Can you give me please a link or some examples used in services?

Comment: WorkManager is supposed to replace the service+AlarmManager system. You don’t need to start a service inside your WorkManager, just make it do what the service does.

Comment: Thank you I tried to do it with WorkManager and it works except for Chinese Rom's they kill those services and these things.